# PulseAudio: Microphone Volume Increases

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

I have PulseAudio Volume Control installed on my Ubuntu machine. I have noticed that after I plug in my headset and join a call, the built-in microphone's volume goes up to 100%, which makes it so the next time I try to use my built-in mic, it sounds like an earrape and it's too loud. So now, before recording or calling with my built in mic, I have to slide the slider down a lot to get it to sound right.

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening? I would also accept an answer that can somehow set a default mic volume if there's no way to prevent it from changing while calling/recording with  a headset.

Thanks!